# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Validator]

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I'm unable to deploy my project after migrating it from Java EE 6 to Java EE 7.

I already have CDI enabled (beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="all" for backwards compatibility)

The deployment error does not seem to be related to my code since it mentions a "Validator" class trying to be injected at `org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor`

I don't have a clue of what is going on here.

I'm using GlassFish 4.0. Here's the stack trace of the exception generated at deployment time:

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Validator] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator]
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Is this a WAR or an EAR? My first guess is it has to do with your change in the beans.xml file as Weld is now picking things up it probably wouldn't have before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of hours testing out this problem, i concluded its related to an incompatibility issue between Apache MyFaces CODI (CDI Extension) and Java EE 7. You can test it on your own by creating an empty Java EE 7 project (Netbeans + Glassfish 4.0) and adding the library, their last release can be downloaded from [Here](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/download.html)

I was using this extension cause of its @ViewAccessScoped implementation. I replaced it by the new JSF 2.2 annotation javax.faces.view.ViewScoped which actually works with CDI

Comment: Sorry, but that answer isn't very useful. Just don't add the Bean-Validation module from CODI. The majority of its functionality is available in EE7 out-of-the-box

Comment: Others had no issue with doing it. See e.g. the comment in the last part of http://jsfcorner.blogspot.co.at/2013/08/from-codi-to-deltaspike.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing this as well, plus a very similar problem with Guava 14.0.1.

The root cause of this seems to be that the default behaviour of CDI changed from 1.0 to 1.1. In 1.0, CDI didn't do *anything* with an archive unless a beans.xml was present. In 1.1, a missing beans.xml is equivalent to one with bean-discovery-mode=annotated.

In other words, if you have any libraries in your archive that make use of CDI injection annotations but contain no beans.xml, these will now trigger injection attempts.